# I'm trying to run build compton-conf but it's telling me "no targets specified and no makefile found. stop."

Tags: linux, arch-linux, cmake

I'm trying to build [compton-conf](https://github.com/lxqt/compton-conf), but I keep getting that in the title. I'm running Arch Linux.

I'm new to Linux but I build a couple programs before I didn't get any errors.

`ls` into the directory gives me:

```
[abdullah@abdullah ~]$ cd compton-conf
[abdullah@abdullah compton-conf]$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[abdullah@abdullah compton-conf]$ ls
AUTHORS    CMakeLists.txt    compton-conf.desktop.in  COPYING         maindialog.ui
autostart  compton-conf      compton.conf.example     maindialog.cpp  README.md
CHANGELOG  compton-conf.cpp  compton-conf.h           maindialog.h    translations
[abdullah@abdullah compton-conf]$ scrot -u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is based on `cmake` build tool.

You should generate `Makefile` before by running `cmake` in the current project directory.

Then, you can run `make`.

For more info see [man 1 cmake](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmake).

Comment: Thank you!!! i did the cmake then make then make install. it gave me an error and i didn't know what to do so i removed everything and tried again. the same error happened then realized i had to run in sudo....